# Firefox issue when I used position fixed on table row

Tags: html, position, html-table, head

I need scrollable header for tables. So I decided to use postion: fixed on styles. The problem is the width is shrinked on Firefox & Chrome. It works fine on Mozilla. For your reference I posted my HTML table code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <table width="150%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th width="50%" align="left">Head 1</th>
            <th width="50%" align="left">Head 2</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
         <tr><td>Foot 1</td></tr>
      </tfoot>
   </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 <th align="left" style="position:fixed;float:left;">Head 1</th>
 <th align="left" style="position:fixed;float:right;left:75%;">Head 2</th>
```

Comment: I have tried this. It am not looking for this, the scroll bar comes for the table. I don't want the scroll for table, the scroll bar will come for the entire page and the table header needs to be scrollable for vertical as well as horizontal.

Comment: Note: My table width is 150% not 100%

Comment: It's working find for horizontal scrolling. Not working for vertical scrolling.

Comment: In that case,there also have some answers about that.take a look at [html-table-scrolling-vertical-horizontal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191451/html-table-scrolling-vertical-horizontal)