# Implementing in-place select in extended table rich faces suggestion for better solution and performance issue

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Hi I would like implement a editable table with both horizontal and vertical scroll bars so i chosen extended table in rich faces and want to edit the data in this table so i chosen the in-place input and in-place select ,
works good if i  have less than 30 rows, if i have more rows say 600 rows.....it is dead slow to render the page

with out in-place selects just i tried display it works so nice so the reason i thought is the following because  ,
each row has 6 in-place selects so it is too slow because it needs to load 600*6 =3600 select drop downs and for each drop down it is going to modal class to get the pick list for each drop down.

these 6 drop downs are repeated in each row of these 600 rows....so is there any way to improve performance and use this solution or is there any good solution for this one ?

Is there any way store the drop down options in one variable on rich faces client side and re use on the same page?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"

    >

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/layout/baseLayoutJs.xhtml">

<rich:messages layout="list" showDetail="true" showSummary="true"
        style="color:darkred">
        <f:facet name="errorMarker">
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/error.gif" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="infoMarker">
            <h:graphicImage value="/images/passed.gif" />
        </f:facet>
    </rich:messages>
    <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form>
                    <rich:panel style="width:800px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGrid id="grid0" columns="4" style="width:800px;">
                        <h:outputLabel for="s1212" styleClass="formLabelswidth25"
                            value="Scheme Editor Home" />

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>
                <rich:messages layout="list" rendered="true" showDetail="true"
                    showSummary="true" passedLabel="Trying to Save." style="color:red">
                    <f:facet name="errorMarker">
                        <h:graphicImage value="/images/error.gif" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="passedMarker">
                        <h:graphicImage value="/images/passed.gif" />
                    </f:facet>
                </rich:messages>

                <h:panelGrid columns="8" bgcolor="#BED6F8" style="height:30px;" width="780">
                    <h:commandButton action="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.saveScheme}" value="Save" style="height:20px;width:60px;"/>
                        <h:commandButton action="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.addNewSchemeRow}" value="New Row" style="height:20px;width:10x;"/>
                <h:commandButton action="#" value="Clear Row" style="height:20px;width:100px;"/>
                                    <h:commandButton action="#" value="Delete Row" style="height:20px;width:100px;"/>
                    <h:commandButton action="#" value="Update Trays" style="height:20px;width:100px;"/>
                        <h:commandButton action="#" value="Search" style="height:20px;width:100px;"/>
                            <h:commandButton action="#" value="Copy" style="height:20px;width:100px;"/>
                            <h:commandButton action="#" value="Help" style="height:20px;width:100px;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                    <t:div style=" height : 10px;"></t:div>
                <h:panelGrid id="searchData" style="width=780px;">


                    <rich:extendedDataTable id="data" var="list"
                    preserveDataModel="false"   preserveSort="true"  bgcolor="#BED6F8"  style="height:300px; width:780px;"
                    frozenColumns="3" 
                    selection="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.selection}" selectionMode="multiple"
                    value="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.sortSchemeRowList}" width="780"   rowKeyVar="row">

                  <rich:column align="left" width="130px" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:panelGroup width="130px" layout="block">

                         <script type="text/javascript">
                        //<![CDATA[
                            function checkAllCheckboxesInTable( inputId, state ){

                              var commonIdPart = inputId.substr(0, inputId.lastIndexOf(':'));

                              var tableId = commonIdPart ;

                              var tableElement = document.getElementById( tableId );

                              var inputs = tableElement.getElementsByTagName('input');

                              for (var i = 0; i <= inputs.length; i++){
                                  var input = inputs[i];
                                  if( input.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox' && state){
                                    input.setAttribute('checked', state);
                                  }else{
                                    input.removeAttribute('checked');
                                  }
                              }
                            }
                            //]]>
                          </script>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkAll" title="#{bundle.CHECK_ALL}" onclick="checkAllCheckboxesInTable( this.id, this.checked );">
                          <a4j:ajax event="change" reRender="data"/>
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        <h:outputText  value=" SELECT ALL"  styleClass="formLabelswidth29"   />

                      </h:panelGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox align="left" id="checkEntry" value="#{list.selected}" disabled="false"/>
                  </rich:column>





                <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Start Bin"  styleClass="formLabelswidth29" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:inplaceInput layout="block" value="#{list.startBin}"
                        converterMessage="Start Bin value should be integer. Start Bin at row #{row+1} can't be changed."
                        id="inplace" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Start Bin at row #{row+1} wasn't filled. Value can't be changed."
                        changedHoverClass="hover" viewHoverClass="hover"
                        viewClass="inplace" changedClass="inplace" style="border-style:none;"
                        selectOnEdit="true" >



                    </rich:inplaceInput>
                    </rich:column>

                        <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="End Bin" styleClass="formLabelswidth29"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:inplaceInput layout="block" value="#{list.endBin}"
                        converterMessage="End Bin value should be integer. End Bin  at row #{row+1} can't be changed."
                        id="inplace2" required="true"
                        requiredMessage=" End Bin at row #{row+1} wasn't filled. Value can't be changed."
                        changedHoverClass="hover" viewHoverClass="hover"
                        viewClass="inplace" changedClass="inplace" style="border-style:none;"
                        selectOnEdit="true" >



                    </rich:inplaceInput>
                    </rich:column>


                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Bin Switch" styleClass="formLabelswidth29"/>
                     </f:facet>

                     <rich:inplaceSelect   value="#{list.binSwitch}"   style="border-style:none;" selectItemClass="SelectItem" >
                       <f:selectItems value="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.binSwitchTypeList}" />
                    </rich:inplaceSelect>

                </rich:column>


               <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Bin Type" styleClass="formLabelswidth29" />
                     </f:facet>

                     <rich:inplaceSelect   value="#{list.binTypeId}"   style="border-style:none;" selectItemClass="SelectItem" >
                       <f:selectItems value="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.binTypeList}" />
                    </rich:inplaceSelect>

                </rich:column>    


               <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Qual Level" styleClass="formLabelswidth29" />
                     </f:facet>

                     <rich:inplaceSelect   value="#{list.quailificationLevelId}"   style="border-style:none;" selectItemClass="SelectItem" >
                       <f:selectItems value="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.sortLevelTypeList}" />
                    </rich:inplaceSelect>

                </rich:column>    



               <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Auto/Mach" styleClass="formLabelswidth29" />
                     </f:facet>

                     <rich:inplaceSelect   value="#{list.autoMachinableId}"   style="border-style:none;" selectItemClass="SelectItem" >
                       <f:selectItems value="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.autoMachTypeList}" />
                    </rich:inplaceSelect>

                </rich:column>                      




                        <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Zip Range" styleClass="formLabelswidth29" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:inplaceInput  value="#{list.rangeValue}"
                        converterMessage="Zip Range value should be integer. Zip Range at row #{row+1} can't be changed."
                        id="inplace3" required="false"
                        requiredMessage="Zip Range at row #{row+1} wasn't filled. Value can't be changed."

                        selectOnEdit="true" style="p {display:block};border-style:none;"  >



                    </rich:inplaceInput>
                    </rich:column>


                        <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Bin Line 1" styleClass="formLabelswidth29" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:inplaceInput layout="block" value="#{list.binLine1}"
                        converterMessage="Bin Line 1 value should be integer. Bin Line 1 at row #{row+1} can't be changed."
                        id="inplace4" 
                        requiredMessage="Bin Line 1 at row #{row+1} wasn't filled. Value can't be changed."
                        changedHoverClass="hover" viewHoverClass="hover"
                        viewClass="inplace" changedClass="inplace" style="border-style:none;"
                        selectOnEdit="true" minInputWidth="180px" >
                        <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="5" />


                    </rich:inplaceInput>

                    </rich:column>

                                            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Bin Line 2" styleClass="formLabelswidth29" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <rich:inplaceInput layout="block" value="#{list.binLine2}"
                        converterMessage="Bin Line 2 value should be integer. Bin Line 2 at row  #{row+1}        can't be changed."
                        id="inplace5"
                        requiredMessage="Bin Line 2 at row #{row+1} wasn't filled. Value can't be changed."
                        changedHoverClass="hover" viewHoverClass="hover"
                        viewClass="inplace" changedClass="inplace" style="border-style:none;"
                        selectOnEdit="true" >



                    </rich:inplaceInput>
                    </rich:column>



                    </rich:extendedDataTable>



            </h:panelGrid>

                </rich:panel>
                    <t:saveState value="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.selectedSchemeId}"></t:saveState>

        <t:saveState value="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.sortSchemeRowList}"></t:saveState>
                    <t:saveState value="#{schemeWebEditorHomeHandler.fromAddNewRow}"></t:saveState>
                </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

here is my bean

new code

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
   public class SchemeWebEditorHomeHandler extends BaseHandler implements
        Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1172151714140365016L;
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SchemeWebEditorHomeHandler.class);

    private List<SortSchemeRow> sortSchemeRowList;
    List<SelectItem> binSwitchTypeList;
    boolean fromAddNewRow = false;
    List<SelectItem> binTypeList;
    List<SelectItem> autoMachTypeList;
    List<SelectItem> sortLevelTypeList;
    List<SelectItem> planetCodeTypeList;
    List<SelectItem> subMailTypeList;
    List<SelectItem> trayLabelTypeList;
    List<SelectItem> msMailTypeList;
    List<SelectItem> trayBandingTypeList;
    private Collection<Object> selection;
    private int selectedSchemeId;

    public SchemeWebEditorHomeHandler() throws BaajaException {

        binSwitchTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        binSwitchTypeList.add(new SelectItem(1, "ON"));
        binSwitchTypeList.add(new SelectItem(2, "OF"));

        SchemeExpertService schemeExpert = (SchemeExpertService) ServiceLocator
                .getServiceWithName(SchemeExpertService.class.getName());

        // binTypeList fetch
        if (this.binTypeList == null || this.binTypeList.size() <= 0) {
            Collection machBinTypeList = schemeExpert.getMachBinTypes();
            this.binTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (Iterator iterator = machBinTypeList.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                MachSchemeBinType machSchemeBinType = (MachSchemeBinType) iterator
                        .next();
                this.binTypeList.add(new SelectItem(machSchemeBinType
                        .getSchemeBinTypeId(), machSchemeBinType
                        .getDisplayDescription()));
            }
        }

        if (this.autoMachTypeList == null || this.autoMachTypeList.size() <= 0) {
            Collection dbAutoMAchTypeList = schemeExpert
                    .getAutoMachinableTypes();
            this.autoMachTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

            for (Iterator iterator = dbAutoMAchTypeList.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                CoreAutoMachLite coreAutoMachLite = (CoreAutoMachLite) iterator
                        .next();
                this.autoMachTypeList.add(new SelectItem(coreAutoMachLite
                        .getAutoMachId(), coreAutoMachLite.getDescription()));

            }
        }

        if (this.sortLevelTypeList == null
                || this.sortLevelTypeList.size() <= 0) {
            Collection dbSortLevelTypeList = schemeExpert
                    .getQualificationLevels();
            this.sortLevelTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (Iterator iterator = dbSortLevelTypeList.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                CoreSortLevelLite coreSortLevelLite = (CoreSortLevelLite) iterator
                        .next();

                this.sortLevelTypeList.add(new SelectItem(coreSortLevelLite
                        .getSortLevelId(), coreSortLevelLite.getDescription()));

            }
        }

        planetCodeTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        planetCodeTypeList.add(new SelectItem(true, "ON"));
        planetCodeTypeList.add(new SelectItem(false, "OF"));

        if (this.subMailTypeList == null || this.subMailTypeList.size() <= 0) {
            Collection dbSubMailTypeList = schemeExpert.getSubMailingTypes();
            this.subMailTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (Iterator iterator = dbSubMailTypeList.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                MachSubmailTypeLite machSubmailTypeLite = (MachSubmailTypeLite) iterator
                        .next();

                this.subMailTypeList.add(new SelectItem(machSubmailTypeLite
                        .getSubmailTypeId(), machSubmailTypeLite
                        .getDescription()));

            }
        }

        if (this.msMailTypeList == null || this.msMailTypeList.size() <= 0) {
            Collection dbmsMailTypeList = schemeExpert.getMsMailingTypes();
            this.msMailTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (Iterator iterator = dbmsMailTypeList.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                MsMailTypeLite msMailTypeLite = (MsMailTypeLite) iterator
                        .next();

                this.msMailTypeList.add(new SelectItem(msMailTypeLite
                        .getMsMailTypeId(), msMailTypeLite.getDescription()));

            }
        }

        trayBandingTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        trayBandingTypeList.add(new SelectItem(true, "ON"));
        trayBandingTypeList.add(new SelectItem(false, "OF"));

        if (this.trayLabelTypeList == null
                || this.trayLabelTypeList.size() <= 0) {
            Collection dbtrayLabelTypeList = schemeExpert
                    .getTraySubMailingTypes();
            this.trayLabelTypeList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (Iterator iterator = dbtrayLabelTypeList.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                LogTrayTagTypeLite logTrayTagTypeLite = (LogTrayTagTypeLite) iterator
                        .next();

                this.trayLabelTypeList.add(new SelectItem(logTrayTagTypeLite
                        .getTrayTagTypeId(), logTrayTagTypeLite
                        .getDescription()));

            }
        }


        log.info("Constrctor ...........");

    }


    public String viewScheme() throws BaajaException {
        SchemeExpertService schemeExpert = (SchemeExpertService) ServiceLocator
                .getServiceWithName(SchemeExpertService.class.getName());
        HttpServletRequest req = getServletRequest();
        int sorterSchemeId = this.selectedSchemeId;
        if (req.getParameter("sorterSchemeId") != null
                && req.getParameter("sorterSchemeId").trim().length() > 0) {
            sorterSchemeId = Integer.parseInt(req
                    .getParameter("sorterSchemeId"));

        }
        log.info("Parameter scheme Id :" + sorterSchemeId);
        MachSorterSchemeLite sortScheme = schemeExpert
                .getScheme(sorterSchemeId);
        this.sortSchemeRowList = (List) SortSchemeUtility
                .getSortSchemeRow(sortScheme.getMachSortSchemeGroups());
        if (sortSchemeRowList.size() > 0) {

        } else {
            addErrorMessage("No matching records found for selected criteria");
        }
        return "view_SchemeWebHome_Screen";
    }

    public String saveScheme() throws BaajaException {
        System.out.println("Hello inside save scheme");
        // log.info("listSize5"+this.sortSchemeRowList.size());
        // sortSchemeRowList= getSortSchemeRowList();

        SchemeExpertService schemeExpert = (SchemeExpertService) ServiceLocator
                .getServiceWithName(SchemeExpertService.class.getName());

        MachSorterSchemeLite sortScheme = schemeExpert
                .getScheme(this.selectedSchemeId);

        schemeExpert.updateSchemeWithSorterSchemeGroup(sortScheme,
                SortSchemeUtility.getSortSchemeGroups(
                        (Collection) this.sortSchemeRowList, sortScheme));

        return viewScheme();
    }

    public String addNewSchemeRow() throws BaajaException {
        log.info("listSize" + this.sortSchemeRowList.size());
        SortSchemeRow sr = new SortSchemeRow();
        sr.setSubMailingTypeId(1);
        sr.setGroupSeparator("");
        sr.setBinSwitch(1);
        sr.setAutoMachinableId(1);
        sr.setBinTypeId(1);
        sr.setQuailificationLevelId(1);

        this.sortSchemeRowList.add(sr);
        // log.info(getSortSchemeRowList().size()+"listSize2"+this.sortSchemeRowList.size());
        setFromAddNewRow(true);
        return "view_SchemeWebHome_Screen";
    }

    public List<SortSchemeRow> getSortSchemeRowList() throws BaajaException {
        SchemeExpertService schemeExpert = (SchemeExpertService) ServiceLocator
        .getServiceWithName(SchemeExpertService.class.getName());

        if (this.sortSchemeRowList == null || sortSchemeRowList.size() <= 0) {
            if (!this.fromAddNewRow) {
                HttpServletRequest req = getServletRequest();
                if (req.getParameter("sorterSchemeId") != null) {
                    this.selectedSchemeId = Integer.parseInt(req
                            .getParameter("sorterSchemeId"));
                }
                log.info("Parameter scheme Id :" + this.selectedSchemeId);
                MachSorterSchemeLite sortScheme = schemeExpert
                        .getScheme(this.selectedSchemeId);
                sortSchemeRowList = (List) SortSchemeUtility
                        .getSortSchemeRow(sortScheme.getMachSortSchemeGroups());
            }
        }
        if (sortSchemeRowList.size() > 0) {
            return sortSchemeRowList;
        } else {
            addErrorMessage("No matching records found for selected criteria");
        }
        return sortSchemeRowList;
    }

    public void setSortSchemeRowList(List<SortSchemeRow> sortSchemeRowList) {
        this.sortSchemeRowList = sortSchemeRowList;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getBinSwitchTypeList() {
        return binSwitchTypeList;
    }
    public boolean isFromAddNewRow() {
        return fromAddNewRow;
    }
    public void setFromAddNewRow(boolean fromAddNewRow) {
        this.fromAddNewRow = fromAddNewRow;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getBinTypeList() throws BaajaException {
        return binTypeList;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getAutoMachTypeList() throws BaajaException {
        log.info("autoMachTypeList ...........");
        return autoMachTypeList;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getSortLevelTypeList() throws BaajaException {
        return sortLevelTypeList;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getPlanetCodeTypeList() {
        return planetCodeTypeList;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getSubMailTypeList() throws BaajaException {
        return subMailTypeList;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getTrayLabelTypeList() throws BaajaException {
        return trayLabelTypeList;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getMsMailTypeList() throws BaajaException {
        return msMailTypeList;
    }
    public List<SelectItem> getTrayBandingTypeList() {
        return trayBandingTypeList;
    }
    public Collection<Object> getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }
    public void setSelection(Collection<Object> selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }
    public int getSelectedSchemeId() {
        return selectedSchemeId;
    }
    public void setSelectedSchemeId(int selectedSchemeId) {
        this.selectedSchemeId = selectedSchemeId;
    }

}
```

Comment: It would heavily depend how have you built your page and followed best practices, like using pagination, having no business logic on getters/setters, using the right bean scopes, etc. Without piece of code to analyze, there's no way to say you how to enhance your application.

Comment: i need the both horizontal and vertical scroll bars ,i cant use pagination,i have code but it is too large to post here ,simple as i said i need editable table with 6 drop downs each row,these drop downs are repeated in each and every row.all i need to know witout going to modal is there any way to fetch the options for these drop downs ?

Comment: Is there any way store the drop down options in one variable on rich faces client side and re use on the same page?

Comment: Yes, it is. As I've said, you haven't posted any code to analyze the problems you're facing.

Comment: Hi   Luiggi Mendoza i just added the code ,Please hlep me

Comment: The main problem is that you're refilling the `List<SelectItem>` on getter. Please refer to [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197) and redesign your managed bean. Also, if you don't use PrimeFaces in your page, just delete the reference. One more tip, make your bean at least `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: ok i moved all drop down options getter filled in constructor and cleaned up can u plz take look yet it still taking a 1 mint to load around 600 rows with inplace edit in the table

Comment: After reading the link in my last comment, it looks that you haven't worked on removing all the business logic in your getters and setters i.e. `getSortSchemeRowList`. You should load data in: 1. Managed bean constructor, 2. Managed bean `@PostConstruct` annotated method, 3. `UICommand`s action like `<h:commandButton>`/`<h:commandLink>` and/or 4. `<f:ajax>` listener method.

Comment: One more tip, you **should** use pagination when data is bigger as this, otherwise you will have performance problems when loading your web page (I've worked with no-pagination datatables with more than 200 rows using JSF and Spring MVC and the performance is pretty similar in both =\).

Comment: is it possible to add pagination to a extended data table with both horizontal and vertical scroll bars, i need to add both horizontal and vertical bars this is must and should requirement for my current project.

Comment: Remember that in the end the JSF/RichFaces code will generate a plain `<table>` HTML component, so that's just a matter of style on the table. Refer to [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2191451/1065197) to solve that problem.

Comment: Thank You so much finally ,i got approved by my busness team with pagination and resolved .Thanks lot for all l you support Luiggi Mendoza and also the group.

Comment: You're welcome :). Glad to know you solved the problem.