# Style HTML Table into Body of Page with Separate Header and Footer files using CSS

Tags: css, html

I am using separate header and footer files in my web page, i have included the CSS file into the header and footer files. NowI want to style a table in my page i.e. want to add vertical and horizontal scroll bars.

below is my illustration.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                header foo1.php                                    |
|    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css">     |   
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Body            foo2.php                                          |
|   **Table placed Here**                                           |
|                                                                   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|            Footer foo3.php                                        |
|    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css">     |
|                                                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The footer and the header use the CSS file the body does not.

Below is the code for the table.

```html
   <div id=wrapper>
  <table id=wrapper >
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="6"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="center"><strong>ID</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>FirstName</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Request</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Purpose</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Description</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Booking Time</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Access Time</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Exit Time</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Approved</strong></td>
                <td align="center"><strong>Approved By</strong></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="id" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>

<td align="center">
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $rows['fisrt_name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['last_name']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="description" type="text" id="description" value="<?php echo $rows['description']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="description" type="text" id="request" value="<?php echo $rows['request']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="description" type="text" id="description" value="<?php echo $rows['description']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="description" type="text" id="booking_time" value="<?php echo $rows['booking_time']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="description" type="text" id="access_time" value="<?php echo $rows['access_time']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="description" type="text" id="exit_time" value="<?php echo $rows['exit_time']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="description" type="text" id="approved" value="<?php echo $rows['approved']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="description" type="text" id="approved_by" value="<?php echo $rows['approved_by']; ?>" size="15">
</td>


</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

below is the code for the CSS

```css
div.wrapper{
height:500px;
widht:500px;
overflow:auto;

}
```

below is the current picture of the page

[image: current loo of the table]

Comment: What issues are you having? You ned to post your desired result.

Comment: Also, you only need to include the same css file in your header.

Comment: I am not able to make the table scrollable and cannot fix a height and width for the table

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Before it gets closed, here is a link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp . You need to spend a lot of time learning css. Always search before just asking a question.

Comment: An id should be assigned once. And `div.wrapper` does not match `div#wrapper`

Comment: I have just one css file and it included in the headdr and footer files

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table scrolling vertical & horizontal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191451/html-table-scrolling-vertical-horizontal)

Comment: Yes, you only need to include it once.

Comment: When I try that , the width of the table is reduced and some columns left out but does not scroll . by the way am using chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `table` and `div` elements have the same `ID`. You cannot have two elements with the same `ID`. If you want to give both of them the same name (`wrapper` in your case) then change ID to class. So, give them a class name of `wrapper` and remove the `ID` name.

Comment: thanks for the correction but the problem persist. Ok will add a picture of the table.